# Alternative to the MySQL datetime '0000-00-00 00:00:00' default value

Tags: mysql, datetime

Since the 5.7 version, MySQL Datetime no longer accept '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as default value. 
Given the fact that all of my scripts rely on this default value when it comes to check datetimes, I'm a bit annoyed as I will have to reshape some parts of my code.
Moreover I can't find any clear explanation and alternative regarding this matter.
So I have 3 questions:

1) Why MySQL no longer accept '0000-00-00 00:00:00' as datetime default value ?

2) Should I replace it with NULL or '1000-01-01 00:00:00' ?

3) What is the best alternative ?

Thanks

Comment: Mysql 5.7 does support the zero date, so I do not really understand your question.

Comment: Question 2 - choose whichever is the best fit for your needs.